# Compare Two List Of Objects For Synchronization

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Let's say I have a class,

```
Class A
{
    ID;
    Name;
    LastModifiedDate;
}
```

and I have Two List's, ListA1 and ListA2,

```
ListA1 = new List<A>(); 
ListA2 = new List<A>();

ListA1.Add(new A{ ID=1, Name="A", LastModifiedDate='1/1/2000' })
ListA1.Add(new A{ ID=2, Name="B", LastModifiedDate='1/2/2000' })
ListA1.Add(new A{ ID=3,Name="C", LastModifiedDate='1/2/2000' })
...................................................


ListA2.Add(new A{ ID=4, Name="D", LastModifiedDate='1/4/2000' })
ListA2.Add(new A{ ID=1, Name="A", LastModifiedDate='1/5/2000' })
ListA3.Add(new A{ ID=2, Name="B", LastModifiedDate='1/2/2000' })
```

Now, I need to compare ListA1 and ListA2 by comparing LastModifiedDate. I need two new List's, describing what are new/updated items in ListA1 and  describing what are new/updated items in ListA2.

**Update**: The output I ma looking is that,

```
newUpadtedListA ={
    new A{ ID=4, Name="D", LastModifiedDate='1/4/2000' },
    new A{ ID=1, Name="A", LastModifiedDate='1/5/2000' }
}

newUpadtedListB ={
    new A{ ID=3, Name="C", LastModifiedDate='1/2/2000' }
}
```

Comment: If the last date modified in list one is newer than that in list two will this be an update or new item? I take it if the second list has a newer date modified it is an update?

Comment: @LukeHennerley, Yes if exist in the new list then update otherwise add.

Comment: Could you say more exactly what the output should be? It's very vague now

Comment: @CuongLe a typo, I guess

Comment: So `LastModifiedDate` is not the key but the combination of ID and Name or only ID?

Comment: Why do you want to get two lists when you could just have one syncronized list which will hold all of the information? Have one list which will hold "current" and one which holds the "possible updates" and then make "current" reflect what is required to change as per my answer.

Comment: @LukeHennerley, You can think that you have records in two different database tables. Now, you need to find what is new/updated in db1 and db2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq and [`Enumerable.Except`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
var a1Modified = ListA1.Select(x => x.LastModifiedDate);
var a2Modified = ListA2.Select(x => x.LastModifiedDate);
var a1NotInA2LastModified = a1Modified.Except(a2Modified);
List<A> newInA1 = (from a1 in ListA1
              join notInA2 in a1NotInA2LastModified
              on a1.LastModifiedDate equals notInA2
              select a1).ToList();
```

and the opposite, what's new in `List2`:

```
var a2NotInA1LastModified = a2Modified.Except(a1Modified);
List<A> newInA2 = (from a2 in ListA2
              join notInA1 in a2NotInA1LastModified
              on a2.LastModifiedDate equals notInA1
              select a2).ToList();
```

**Edit**: according to your last edit that `ID` is the only key column. This should give you all you need in a fairly efficient way:

```
var a1IDs = ListA1.Select(a => a.ID);
var a2IDs = ListA2.Select(a => a.ID);
var newInA1 = from l1 in ListA1
              join newA1 in a1IDs.Except(a2IDs)
              on l1.ID equals newA1
              select l1;
var newInA2 = from l2 in ListA2
              join newA2 in a2IDs.Except(a1IDs)
              on l2.ID equals newA2
              select l2;
var updatedInA1 = from l1 in ListA1
                  join l2 in ListA2
                  on l1.ID equals l2.ID
                  where l1.LastModifiedDate > l2.LastModifiedDate
                  select l1;
var updatedInA2 = from l2 in ListA2
                  join l1 in ListA1
                  on l2.ID equals l1.ID
                  where l2.LastModifiedDate > l1.LastModifiedDate
                  select l2;
```

You can enumerate these sequences and do whatever you need to do to add or update the new/changed items.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var ListA1 = new AList();
  var ListA2 = new AList();

  ListA1.Add(new A { ID = 1, Name = "A", LastModifiedDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01) });
  ListA1.Add(new A { ID = 2, Name = "B", LastModifiedDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01) });
  ListA1.Add(new A { ID = 3, Name = "C", LastModifiedDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01) });

  ListA2.Add(new A { ID = 4, Name = "D", LastModifiedDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 02) });
  ListA2.Add(new A { ID = 1, Name = "A", LastModifiedDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 02) });
  ListA2.Add(new A { ID = 2, Name = "B", LastModifiedDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 02) });

  ListA1.CompareList(ListA2);
```

Now I am comparing ListA1 to ListA2 and when this happens, you should in theory want ID 4 from ListA2 to be added to ListA1 and then ID 1 and 2 be updated so the output should be

```
ID 1 - 2012/01/02
ID 2 - 2012/01/02
ID 3 - 2012/01/01
ID 4 - 2012/01/02
```

Please use this code for the output

```
  public class AList : List<A>
  {
    public void CompareList(List<A> SecondaryList)
    {
      var compareResults = (from a in SecondaryList
                           join b in this on a.ID equals b.ID into gj
                           from subset in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { IsNew = (subset == null),
                                        IsUpdate = (subset != null && a.LastModifiedDate > subset.LastModifiedDate),
                                        Output = a}).ToList();
      foreach (var compareResult in compareResults)
      {
        if (compareResult.IsNew)
          this.Add(compareResult.Output);
        else if (compareResult.IsUpdate)
          this[this.IndexOf(this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == compareResult.Output.ID))] = compareResult.Output;
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT : I made a mistake, should of been `a.LastModifiedDate > subset.LastModifiedDate` instead of `subset.LastModifiedDate > a.LastModifiedDate` in the setting of update and also there was a small problem in the loop.

So what I am basically doing is doing a "left join" based on the ID. So where the ID doesn't join it returns null, however we always want the output to be the "secondary list" this is because should we need to update or edit then we need to use the objects from list 2. If there is a null it means that it doesn't exist in list one hence we set `IsNew` to true and `IsUpdate` is set if the return is not null and the return result has a newer date modified.

Comment: Please see the edit to fix the problem - What wasn't working?

Comment: I put this in new console app and getting error. Try it yourself.

Comment: @user960567 I have this in a console application and it is working perfectly fine and giving the output that I said, otherwise I wouldn't post it...

Comment: OK, Sorry for that. This also works. I need more testing to choose the best one. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously my code is a bit shorter as this does everything at once, efficiency wise I don't know what is better really, let me know if you don't understand any of this